# Web scraping with Python without loading the whole page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I just started few web scraping projects with Python. I currently use lxml, Beautiful Soup and requests modules to scrape web pages. I need to know if there is any method to get only the data we need from the websites instead of getting the whole page loaded. The requests module does a GET request and receives the whole, bs4, lxml filters the data only. I tried out Selenium, but that also opens the browser which is not so suitable for a industrial project. I'm not aware about scrapy and splash.

I'm also not looking for the API key method, which is not applicable everywhere.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse engineering the api calls.

You should analyze the network tab for the incoming and outgoing requests and view response for each request. Alternatively you can also copy the request as curl and use postman to analyze the request. Postman has feature unique which generates python code for requests library and urllib library. Most of the sites return `json` response but sometimes however you may get `html` response.

Some sites do not allow scraping.
Make sure to check robot.txt for the website you will be scraping. You can find robot.txt by `www.sitename.com/robots.txt`.

For more info - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPU08ZfP-II&list=PLL2hlSFBmWwwvFk4bBqaPRV4GP19CgZug

Comment: Thanks for the video. I actually knew about the robots.txt thing which are some sort of rules for crawling on the website. I also did analyze the network tab, but I think I haven't done it correctly which was the reason for this problem. Thank you for solving my issues. Stay safe, Have a nice day.